# XML to edit regsitry

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

I was wondering if there is a way to use xml or xml parser to edit registry value. Search the registry for the product version and add a regkey to it.
Like in HKCU/software/yahoo
if version 10
go to yahoomessenger/service and add key

if version 11
go to yahoomessenger/service and add key

something like that.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Not unless someone has written a program to do this.

Remember, XML is just a data format -- raw syntax to serve as a base for writing "languages" that describe data. While the described data could be a program (as in XSLT), (a) it usually isn't and (b) some other program has to read the program and turn it into something that can be executed (interpreter or compiler or whatever).

Microsoft liked to refer to XML as "smart data" for a while. That was misleading at best. XML is *portable* data, but it's still just data. No inherent smarts.

So, yes, someone could write a registry editor which took its instructions in the form of an XML document. But no, XML by itself won't do it; XML by itself doesn't "do" anything.